# How to skip login page for a role in ASP.NET Identity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, roles

I have an existing ASP.NET site with user authorization and authentication for several roles implemented in the built-in ASP.NET Identity framework. After login, each role is directed to its own set of pages. All works fine. Now, for only one of those roles, I want to hide (skip) the login procedure on the UI but maintain the role and all logic behind the role. In other words, the users in this role will be "converted into guests": they can access their own pages without seeing the login page and without providing a username and password. The other roles will continue going through the login procedure for the usual authentication/authorization. Security is not a concern, looking for a simple solution for user convenience. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The roles go on the logged in user only - so what you ask is not possible - you can have them as non logged in, how ever somewhere else is your issue, but with out code I can not help more... please add some code and an example

Comment: Thanks for your input. My question is about the design approach, so coding is a non-issue. I wanted to get some advice on what the best approach would be to pull out a role from the .NET Identity login procedure.